# sbtbuildinfo - Building with multiple projects

Tags: scala, build, jvm, sbt, sbt-buildinfo

I am using sbt to build a multi module project, and I want to use sbt-buildinfo to allow one of the services to have this info in it for debugging and versioning purposes.

The problem with this, is that the sbt-buildinfo plugin seems to only take the library dependencies of the root project and not all the dependencies of the aggregated sub projects. It seems to me that if you run the plugin after the aggregation then the root project would have those dependencies in it and would show up, but they do not. Maybe I'm just not understanding the process here, but that seems reasonable to me.

Now, this worked perfectly fine with one project, but with many sub projects it no longer works. In addition now it no longer even generates the File, I don't know what I'm doing wrong at this point. Here is my build. Any help is appreciated.

```
EclipseKeys.createSrc := EclipseCreateSrc.Default + EclipseCreateSrc.Managed

lazy val sharedSettings = Seq(
    organization := "com.planalytics",
    version      := "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT",
    name         := "Ingestions",
    scalaVersion := "2.11.7",
  exportJars   := true
) ++ net.virtualvoid.sbt.graph.Plugin.graphSettings ++ Defaults.defaultSettings

lazy val sparkVersion = "1.5.1"
lazy val akkaVersion  = "2.3.12"
lazy val sprayVersion = "1.3.3" 
lazy val hadoopVersion = "2.7.1"

lazy val exclusionRules = Seq(ExclusionRule(organization = "org.slf4j"), 
                              ExclusionRule(organization = "org.apache.hadoop"))

lazy val sharedDeps = Seq(libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
          "org.slf4j"       %  "slf4j-log4j12"  % "1.7.10",
          "org.scalacheck"  %% "scalacheck"     % "1.12.0"  % "test",
          "org.scalatest"   %% "scalatest"      % "2.2.4"   % "test",
          "org.scalanlp"    %% "breeze-natives" % "0.11.2"))

lazy val sparkDeps = Seq(libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
          "org.apache.spark"      %% "spark-core"    % sparkVersion  excludeAll(exclusionRules: _*), 
          "org.apache.spark"      %% "spark-sql"     % sparkVersion  excludeAll(exclusionRules: _*), 
          "org.apache.spark"      %% "spark-mllib"   % sparkVersion  excludeAll(exclusionRules: _*), 
          "com.databricks"        %% "spark-csv"     % "1.2.0"       excludeAll(exclusionRules: _*), 
          "org.apache.hadoop"     %  "hadoop-common" % hadoopVersion,
          "org.apache.hadoop"     %  "hadoop-client" % hadoopVersion,
          "org.apache.hadoop"     %  "hadoop-hdfs"   % hadoopVersion,
          "org.apache.hadoop"     %  "hadoop-aws"    % hadoopVersion))
lazy val akkaDeps  = Seq(libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
          "com.typesafe.akka"     %% "akka-actor"    % akkaVersion,
          "com.typesafe.akka"     %% "akka-cluster"  % akkaVersion,
          "com.typesafe.akka"     %% "akka-remote"   % akkaVersion,
          "com.typesafe.akka"     %% "akka-slf4j"    % akkaVersion))
lazy val sprayDeps = Seq(libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
                "io.spray"              %% "spray-can"     % sprayVersion,
          "io.spray"              %% "spray-routing" % sprayVersion,
          "io.spray"              %% "spray-json"    % "1.3.2"))

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
    settings(sharedSettings: _*).
    settings(   
        scalacOptions += "-deprecation",
        javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.8", "target", "1.8"),
        javaOptions   += "-Xmx2G").aggregate(ingestion, services, util).enablePlugins(BuildInfoPlugin).
  settings(
    buildInfoKeys    :=  Seq[BuildInfoKey](name, version, scalaVersion, sbtVersion),
    buildInfoOptions +=  BuildInfoOption.BuildTime,
    buildInfoPackage :=  "com.planalytics",
    buildInfoObject  := "BuildInfo"
  )

lazy val ingestion = Project(
  id = "Ingestion-Engine", 
    base = file("ingestion"),
    settings = Project.defaultSettings ++ sharedSettings ++ sparkDeps ++ akkaDeps ++ sharedDeps).
    settings(
      name := "Ingestion-Engine",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
          "com.github.seratch"    %% "awscala"       % "0.5.+",
      "com.typesafe.akka"     %% "akka-testkit"  % akkaVersion  % "test"
        )
).dependsOn(util)

lazy val services = Project(
  id = "Ingestion-Services", 
  base = file("services"),
  settings = Project.defaultSettings ++ sharedSettings ++ sprayDeps ++ sharedDeps).
  settings(
    name := "Ingestion-Services",
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        "io.spray"              %% "spray-testkit" % sprayVersion % "test"
    )
).dependsOn(ingestion)

lazy val util = Project(
  id = "Ingestion-Util", 
  base = file("util"),
  settings = Project.defaultSettings ++ sharedSettings ++ sparkDeps ++ sharedDeps).
  settings(
    name := "Ingestion-Utils",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        "net.ceedubs" %% "ficus" % "1.1.2"
    ),
  dependencyOverrides ++= Set(
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.4.4"
  )
)
```

I'm also open to any thoughts on my build in general, I feel like I'm doing some things wrong or repetitively, so any suggestions there is appreciated as well. Thanks!